# How to change In Magento order email address format?

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem that i`m playing with for some hours now and is becoming pretty annoyng.

In `System->Configuration->Customer configuration -> Address Templates` Magento offers the users how to format the addresses ( country, city, region, etc ).

My question is how to change from full region name to region code? I also looked into the code in `Mage/Customer/Address` and can not seem to find the solution.

Any ideas please? Thank you.

Comment: I believe you can't change the behaviour without overloading render() function in Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Renderer_Default. Check Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Renderer/Default.php for further investigation.

Comment: Hello muhammedv - Please add this as a answer and I will mark it as the correct one. Added a new entry in `$data` variable in `render` function in the path you specified and it worked. Thank you very much

Comment: I am very happy that your problem is solved, but I am afraid you found the answer yourself :) Also, I cant recommend editing core files as an MCD. I will add an answer including how to overload this function to add new attributes later.

Comment: Didn't edited in the /core/Mage, went in /local/Mage.Still you are right, editing core files is a bad practice, but when the last solution is to edit the core then is good. If you are happy, you should see me how happy I was that was working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

muhammedv is correct. Editing core files is a bad practice. You found the solution but any way here I have added some code to create new module for this. I'm just rewriting the class.

app/code/local/Packagename/Modulename/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Packagename_Modulename>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Packagename_Modulename>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <modulename>
        <class>Packagename_Modulename_Block</class>
      </modulename>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <address_renderer_default>Packagename_Modulename_Block_Customer_Address_Renderer_Default</address_renderer_default>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Packagename/Modulename/Block/Customer/Address/Renderer/Default.php

```
    <?php
    class Packagename_Modulename_Block_Customer_Address_Renderer_Default extends Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Renderer_Default
    {

//your stuff goes here..

    }
```

And finally activate your module in,

app/code/etc/modules/Packagename_Modulename.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Packagename_Modulename>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Packagename_Modulename>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Please comment here if you have any doubt.

Comment: Yes, I implemented this solution and worked. Thank you Elavarasan. Very good solution and avoided the way to modify the core files.